# Move a report item like textbox inside a SSRS report precisely?

Tags: reporting-services

How can we move a report item like textbox inside a SSRS report precisely? by precisely, I mean lets say, move a report item one centimeter towards left?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the textbox then on the right by the property window under **Position > Location**

Answer (score 0):

If you click on TextBook then you see at Right properties window just like below. There you find location. Changing here will move your Textbox

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have set my margins (all of them) to zero and my SSRS reports still prints 1 cm margin on the right. I checked page settings on the printer too.